# The format of the date keeps changing when i'm importing csv data into excel

Tags: excel, vba, csv, date

I'm importing data form a csv file into excel but in the first column which has date time data the date format keeps changing. For the first 12 days of a month it will be in the mm/dd/yyyy format and then from day 13 onward it will be in the dd/mm/yyyy format. I want them all to be in the dd/mm/yyyy format. I also noticed that cells with the dd/mm/yyyy format don't seem to be read as dates as they are positioned to the left of the cell.

Here is the code I am using to import the data

```
 Const NUM_COLS As Long = 26 'how many columns we're copying
    Dim strEnappsysPriceForecastAPI As String, wb As Workbook
    Dim data() As Variant, lr As Long, wsData As Worksheet

 GoFast
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("API links").Select
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Range("B16").Value)
    Set wsData = wb.Worksheets(1)
    lr = LastUsedRow(wsData)    'last row of data
    If lr > 0 Then              'have data?
        data = wsData.Range("A1").Resize(lr, NUM_COLS).Value

    End If 'have any data



    wb.Close

        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Price forecast data").Select
        With Range("A1")
        .Range("A1:K50000").ClearContents
        .Cells(1).Resize(UBound(data, 1), 1).Value = data
        .Range("A2:A50000").NumberFormat = "DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm"
        End With

    GoFast False
```

Basically I have the hyperlink for the csv data in a cell which is opened into a new excel workbook containing all the data. The data should then be copied exactly as it is in the new workbook and inserted into Price forecast data worksheet. After debugging in vba I noticed the dates in the new workbook change format but when i click the hyperlink to the csv file by itself theyre all in the dd/mm/yyyy format. I've tried to format the dates to all be dd/mm/yyyy as seen above buit the command is basically ignored. Ive not seen any other problems like this so does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks.

EDIT: Some screenshots for a better understanding

[image: Screenshot of workbook of csv data which is created through vba code. As you can see dates format change after first 12 days of a month]
Screenshot of workbook of csv data which is created through vba code. As you can see dates format change after first 12 days of a month

[image: And a screenshot of the data when just clicking the hyperlink as you can see the format for the dates is consistent]

And a screenshot of the data when just clicking the hyperlink as you can see the format for the dates is consistent

Comment: `Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Range("B16").Value, Local:=True)` assuming your regional settings are not US.

Comment: As has been discussed in the forum many times, your problem is due to a mismatch between the date format used in the CSV file, and the date format set on your computer (eg Windows Regional Settings).  You can either change the date format on your computer or use an **import** rather than an **open** method to bring it into Excel, at which time you can tell Excel the format of the incoming csv data.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld No, it is not. It's due to the fact that opening a text file in VBA defaults to US formats *regardless of your regional settings*.

Comment: Too late to edit - I should have said it is not *necessarily* to do with regional settings. If the csv format doesn't match US **or** your regional settings, then you will have this problem no matter how you open the file.

Comment: @Ron Rosenfield thanks for the comment, why are some of the dates in dd/mm/yyyy format and others aren't when i Import the data then? Also i'm in the uk so should the format on my computer be dd/mm/yyyy? Edit: just checked the date format on my computer is dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: @Rory Learn something new. Tks.  That seems also true for csv files. In general, though, I'd think an import method would generally be more robust, unless you are absolutely certain that the imported dates will always be in the same format as your regional settings.

Comment: @NoIdea Did you try simply adding the `Local:=True` argument?

Comment: See also @Rory comment. Setting the **local** flag should work if both the CSV file and your regional settings are the same (eg both dmy).  If not, you can use either the Workbook.OpenText method and set that column appropriately, or use Power Query (included in Excel 2010+). If you use the Workbook.OpenText method, you'll need to change the file type to .txt